# Erro na criação de projeto Lumen: Application ready! Build something amazing

Tags: php, laravel

Fiz a instalação seguindo as indicações da documentação, porém ao rodar lumen new [projeto] ele simplesmente retorna a mensagem: Application ready! Build something amazing.,
cria as pastas mais não gera todos arquivos necessários.

O que pode ser?

detalhe

Detalhes:

> lumen -v 
>   Lumen Installer 1.0.2
>    
>   php -v 
>   PHP 7.0.25-1~dotdeb+8.1 (cli) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.25-1~dotdeb+8.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.5.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans